# How to reseed identity in Amazon redshift and how to make it auto increment

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I am wondering how can we `reset/reseed` an `identity` column in `Amazon redshift`

I also want to make an `auto increment` column in my table.

Comment: http://www.sqlhaven.com/amazon-redshift-identity-column-seed-step-behavior-with-copy-command/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this while creating the table.

```
create table test(id bigint identity(1,1))
```

Adding identity column in existing table is not possible, so you need to re-create a new table and then copy your data from existing table. While re-creating you can reset the identity as column as required.

Comment: Is there any way to reseed identity of existing table like we do in SQL server?

Comment: It's possible to reseed an existing column.

Comment: sorry, I was meant, it's not possible to reseed identity column.

You need to create a new table and then copy the content from existing table to a new table.

Comment: create table temp_table (id bigint identity(1,1), name varchar);
insert into temp_table (name) (select name from actual_table);
alter table rename actual_table to old_actual_table;
alter table rename temp_table to actual_table

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar scenario to rest the Identity column in Redshift especially when the table is truncated. Unfortunately I couldn't find any option to reset the identity column. Using the work around of drop and create the table whenever required to rest but this many not work in all the scenarios.